# Keras tensor has an additional dimension and causes wrong results for net.evaluate()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

I'd like to train a neural network in Python and Keras using a metric learning custom loss function. The loss minimizes the distances of the outputs for similar inputs and maximizes the distances between dissimilar ones. The part considering similar inputs is:

```
# function to create a pairwise similarity matrix, i.e
# L[i,j] == 1 for similar samples i, j and 0 otherwise
def build_indicator_matrix(y_, thr=0.1):
    # y_: contains the labels of the samples,
    # samples are similar in case of same label

    # prevent checking equality of floats --> check if absolute
    # differences are below threshold
    lbls_diff = K.expand_dims(y_, axis=0) - K.expand_dims(y_, axis=1)
    lbls_thr = K.less(K.abs(lbls_diff), thr)
    # cast bool tensor back to float32
    L = K.cast(lbls_thr, 'float32')

    # POSSIBLE WORKAROUND
    #L = K.sum(L, axis=2)

    return L

# function to compute the (squared) Euclidean distances between all pairs
# of samples, store in DIST[i,j] the distance between output y_pred[i,:] and y_pred[j,:]
def compute_pairwise_distances(y_pred):
    DIFF = K.expand_dims(y_pred, axis=0) - K.expand_dims(y_pred, axis=1)
    DIST = K.sum(K.square(DIFF), axis=-1)    
    return DIST

# function to compute the average distance between all similar samples
def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    # y_true: contains true labels of the samples
    # y_pred: contains network outputs

    L = build_indicator_matrix(y_true)    
    DIST = compute_pairwise_distances(y_pred)
    return K.mean(DIST * L, axis=1)
```

For training, I pass a numpy array `y` of shape `(n,)` as target variable to `my_loss`. However, I found (using the computational graph in TensorBoard) that the tensorflow backend creates a 2D variable out of `y` (displayed shape `? x ?`), and hence `L` in `build_indicator_matrix` is not 2 but 3-dimensional (shape `? x ? x ?` in TensorBoard). This causes `net.evaulate()` and `net.fit()` to compute wrong results.

Why does tensorflow create a 2D rather than a 1D array? And how does this affect `net.evaluate()` and `net.fit()`?

As quick workarounds I found that either replacing the `build_indicator_matrix()` with static numpy code for computing `L` , or collapsing the "fake" dimension with the line `L = K.sum(L, axis=2)` solves the problem. In the latter case, however, the output of `K.eval(build_indicator_matrix(y))` is of only of shape `(n,)` and not `(n,n)`, so I do not understand why this workaround still yields correct results. Why does tensorflow introduce an additional dimension?

My library versions are:

- keras: 2.2.4
- tensorflow: 1.8.0
- numpy: 1.15.0

Answer (score 0):

This is because `evaluate` and `fit` work in batches.
The first dimension you see in tensorboard is the batch dimension, unknown in advance and therefore denoted `?`.
When using custom metrics, remember the tensors (`y_true` and `y_pred`) you get are the ones corresponding to the batch.

For more info, show us how you call both those functions.